# how to see designer code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i want to see the designer code ..
i want to see how myForm is generated using or extending form

i mean in C# i can see the code in designer.cs file...but in vb.net i am nt able to see that..

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In VB.Net, in order to see the designer files, you have to click the toggle button above the solution explorer (show all files).

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm looking for this answer too. And this is the 2nd time that I return to this answer. :)