# Sub Form of Visual Basic .Net isn't opened correctly

Tags: windows, vb.net, winforms

I designed a Form and it use to the **sub Form**

The **Mainform** is correctly display, but I use some action to show the **sub Form** and set Visible property of **Mainform** to false

The **sub Form** is displayed incorrectly

[image: sub Form]

^^ **Sub Form**

[image: displayed]

^^ **displayed**

MainForm code:

```
Imports SearcherScreen = Osu_Offline_Searcher.My.SearcherScreen

Public Class SearcherOfOsu

    Private ReadOnly SS As New SearcherScreen()
    Private ReadOnly DOF As New DownloadOsuForm()

    Private Sub Downloader_OnDownloadData(sender As OsuDownload.OsuDownloader, e As OsuDownload.OsuDownloader.DownloadDataEventArgs) Handles Downloader.DownloadData

        If DOF.Created Then
            DOF.ChangeProgressBar(e.Present)
        Else

            DOF.Icon = New Icon("osu!.ico")
            DOF.Show()
            Visible = False

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub DetectButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DetectButton.Click

        Dim Detecter As New OsuDetect.DetectClass()
        Dim UserDirectoryName = Detecter.DetectUserDirectory()

        If UserDirectoryName = "No User" Then
            MsgBox("I can't find any User.")
        Else
            Dim OsuDirectoryName = Detecter.DetectOsuDirectory(UserDirectoryName)

            If OsuDirectoryName = "No Osu" Then

                MsgBox("You don't download the Osu in defalut directory.")
                Dim Result = MsgBox("Download Osu now?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Download Osu")

                If Result = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    OsuDirectoryPath.Text = Downloader.DownloadOsu(UserDirectoryName)

                    Visible = True
                    DOF.Close()
                End If

            Else
                OsuDirectoryPath.Text = OsuDirectoryName
            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents Downloader As New OsuDownload.OsuDownloader()

End Class
```

Sub Form:

```
Public Class DownloadOsuForm

    Sub ChangeProgressBar(Value As Integer)
        OsuDownloadProgressBar.Value = Value
        OsuDownloadLabel.Text = "Osu Downloading..."
    End Sub

End Class
```

This the code of forms

and after here is the designer code

Sub Designer Code:

```vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
Partial Class DownloadOsuForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form 覆寫 Dispose 以清除元件清單。
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    '為 Windows Form 設計工具的必要項
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    '注意: 以下為 Windows Form 設計工具所需的程序
    '可以使用 Windows Form 設計工具進行修改。
    '請勿使用程式碼編輯器進行修改。
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar = New System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar()
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'OsuDownloadProgressBar
        '
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(60, 205)
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.Minimum = 0
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.Maximum = 100
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.Value = 0
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.Name = "OsuDownloadProgressBar"
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(280, 30)
        Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'OsuDownloadLabel
        '
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.AutoSize = True
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("新細明體", 12.0!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(136, Byte))
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(105, 155)
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.Name = "OsuDownloadLabel"
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(190, 24)
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.TabIndex = 1
        Me.OsuDownloadLabel.Text = "Osu Downloading..."
        '
        'DownloadOsuForm
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(9.0!, 18.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(400, 400)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.OsuDownloadLabel)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.OsuDownloadProgressBar)
        Me.Margin = New System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1, 3, 1, 3)
        Me.Name = "DownloadOsuForm"
        Me.Text = "Downloading Osu"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents OsuDownloadProgressBar As ProgressBar
    Friend WithEvents OsuDownloadLabel As Label
End Class
```

Comment: Update your question with the code where you call the subform, and your designer code part for the label

Comment: @Martheen I changed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966557/how-to-see-designer-code-in-vb-net we likely need to see the designer code, though at this stage, try enlarging the label size and use standard font for the label

Comment: the desiner code in here

Comment: The form is simply unpainted.  Probably because the main thread is busy downloading, so can't take care of painting, it isn't obvious to me from the snippets how it got started.  Use BackgroundTask or Task or async/await.

Comment: I change it to async and call it by await, but the same result display